# Filling Webform using Selenium WebDriver from Excel

Tags: java, webdriver, data-driven-tests

I have a portal (say a new loyalty card)on which I have to fill a lengthy application form, to verify the final outcome of the application.
If I have data in excel (say, name, DOB, Drivers License, ...)how can I automate it using Selenium WebDriver on Java ? if I can open in multiple browsers then even better :)
(I have been successful in writing the code for a single form, I am looking for help to fill the same form multiple times without needing to touch the code)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Data driven framework, using TestNG.Apache POI library use in your project, that will help to read data dynamically from excel sheet.

Comment: Thank you Monali, I have tried that, but could only get 2 inputs (like, username & password) which is far less than my requirement

Answer (score 1):

You Can use the **Apache POI**  to read the data from excel and **TestNg** to write the test case.Use **@dataProvider** annotation to submit multiple data rows one by one for test case.You can write some class which will have different functions to execute actions like click, sendKeys ,navigate,openBrowser and wait which will be invoked as per the input data from excel file.
ref link - http://toolsq.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/

Sample format for Excel file :
[image]

Comment: Thank you Vijay, I tried this and could only get 2 inputs (username & password), whereas I am looking for filling a form with a lot of inputs like - First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, DOB, Address, etc...